# Apache url canonicalization with mod_jk

Tags: mod-rewrite, mod-jk

I have the domain `domain.gr`.

I have setup an Apache server with `mod_rewrite` and `mod_jk`.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.gr
    ServerAlias www.domain.gr
    ServerAdmin "info@domain.gr"
    DocumentRoot /var/www

    <IfModule jk_module>
        JkMount /myapp/* worker1

        Alias /myapp "/opt/tomcat/webapps/myapp"

        <Directory "/opt/tomcat/webapps/myapp">
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            Allow from all
        </Directory>

        <Location "/myapp/WEB-INF/">
            Deny from all
        </Location>
    </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

All works fine but now i want to canonicalize the URLs.

**I want when i type**

```
domain.gr         -> www.domain.gr
domain.gr/myapp   -> www.domain.gr/myapp
```

**I use the rules**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.gr [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.gr$1 [L,R=301]
```

When i write `domain.gr` it goes to `www.domain.gr`, but when i write `domain.gr/myapp` it doesn't go to `www.domain.gr/myapp`

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Where have you placed those rewrite rules? ie, are they within that  block, or did you put them somewhere else? Perhaps in a .htaccess file?

What happens instead? ie, does it stay at domain.gr/myapp, or does something else happen?

If it's in a .htaccess file, $1 is going to be 'myapp' rather than '/myapp', resulting in a redirect to domain.grmyapp which of course doesn't exist.

Comment: i manage to solved it. I had those rules in httpd.conf but not in VirtualHost tag. When i move them on VirtualHost tag it worked